# How-to upgrade LXC container after `do-release-upgrade` to Wily?

Tags: 15.10, lxc, do-release-upgrade

I have just done a `do-release-upgrade -m server` from

> `Linux boson 3.19.0-31-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:04:02 UTC 2015 x86_64 Linux-3.19.0-31-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-15.04-vivid`

to

> `Linux boson 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 Linux-4.2.0-16-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-15.10-wily`

I had imagined that the LXC containers would automagically be upgraded too. However, although `uname -r` returns `4.2.0-16-generic` which confirms that the kernel is on Wily, doing an `apt-get update` shows that the container is still pointed at the Vivid repository.

`do-release-upgrade` while attached to the container returns `bash: do-release-upgrade: command not found`.

How do I upgrade the LXC containers too? Is there a tool available?

(I don't have X installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also google similar question, and find your question. :)
Before I start testing, I create snapshot for the container, in case I ruin something when I'm trying.
Fortunately, the upgrade is very smooth.

I think container will not be upgrade automatically when host is upgraded.

I've just done an release upgrade from Wily to Xenial for my LXD container. Below is what I'm doing. I think it would be similar for LXC container.

Attach to containter console, you will be root; and you don't need to worry ssh service since you are using console:

```
$ lxc exec <container name> -- bash
```

First upgrade your software packages, especially for apt:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot (maybe not needed)
```

if you don't have "do-release-upgrade":

```
# apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
```

Then you can start upgrade:

```
# do-release-upgrade -m server
```

In case “do-release-upgrade” complains "Must be connected to a terminal.", I have no idea why this happens, I think this container bases on Ubuntu cloud image. So have to use a ssh connection and "sudo"s.

Comment: I'll try this when upgrading to 16.04.1 later this year. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In Proxmox, the first command is `pct exec container-id -- bash`

Answer (score 2):

Cannot comment on @alfred answer so sorry for new one.

"Must be connected to a terminal." complain can be solved with command:

```
exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty
```

Than just run do-release-upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't want/need to pass the upgrader code paths I do like the post that mentioned just replacing the release name in /etc/apt/sources.list.

But If I want/need do-release-upgrade to really run I just enable ssh.
There might be easier ways to get convinced to have a proper console, but it is easy and works.

To do so do

```
# go into the container
lxc exec <container> bash
# set PasswordAuthentication yes here
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# restart containers ssh
service ssh restart
# set a pw of the default ubuntu user
passwd ubuntu
# exit container and get the container IP
lxc info <container>
# connect to it via ssh
ssh ubuntu@<ip>
# run do-release-upgrade as you want
do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what seems to have worked for me:

```
$ sudo lxc-attach --name <container>
```

Then edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace all occurences of `vivid` to `wily`.

Next do:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# apt-get autoclean
# apt-get autoremove
# reboot
```

Repeat this a couple of times until all packages are updated.

Comment: this had no effect for me in 2017, I think the OLD URLs in sources.list no longer work